# Can't find a bash script anywhere in filesystem

Tags: linux, bash, path

I have a bash script that uses ssh and requires 1 positional argument. If I type the name partially, the bash-completion completes it and the script works. The issue is that I can't find it anywhere to look into it. I checked for it in all the directories of `$PATH`, tried `locate` and `find` (without sudo so permission denied on `/proc`) and I can't find it. I am wondering how bash completion is completing it. It's not in the home directory for sure. I am using Debian 11

Comment: Did you try `which`?

Comment: it might not be a bash script but a shell function, so if `which commandname` doesn't help, try `type commandname`

Comment: `which` and `whereis` doesn't work. `type` worked and the output says that it's a function. How can I edit that function?

Comment: Try with: `$ bash --debugger` and then `$ declare -F commandname`.

Comment: @schrodingerscatcuriosity running `bash --debugger` gives no output but then running `declare -F commandname` did give the location of the function. It's in a custom .bash file which is read by `.bashrc`. What's `bash --debugger` is doing here?

Comment: @Cruise5 `bash --debugger` is not meant to give any output. In the [GNU manual of bash](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html) search for `extdebug`, there's an explanation of both `--debugger` and `declare -F`.

Comment: Could it be an alias? Can you try and type ```alias``` in the terminal and see if it is on the list?